# How to get web data which can be opened from a specific website into a different tab in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-web-query

I wont to pull data from a webpage on the basis of a criteria's into excel however I am unable to do so.
Website from which I wont to pull data can be logged in only via another website and not by just url.
For E.g. My site name is Elsc and to login into it I have to via another site Gatekeeper and elsc cannot be logged into in any other way.
So is there a solution to get data from such website by Macro.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried `Import Data from Web page` option under `DATA` tab option in excel for a start ? Which doesn't needs the macro.

Comment: Yes I did ... However it didn't work.. My elsc window open outside the selection box.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Excel will give you this kind of control (controlling one URL from another URL).  I tried to do this a long time ago; it never worked right.  Can you just login to that URL and then run a simple VBA script to download the data?  Also, consider using a Power Query to do this for you.

http://chandoo.org/wp/2015/08/21/import-web-data-power-query/